# Role ACL doesn't work using Parse's Android Local Datastore:

Tags: android, parse-platform

The issue is straightforward:

1. Create a user and add it to a role
2. Create an object and give it role ACL

The user will be able to find and pin the object, however, the object cannot be retrieved from the local datastore. If I switch to user or public ACL, the object is retrieved.

Example:

```
public void findAndPinInBackground(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query, final MyCallback callback) {
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> eventList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(eventList, new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Pinned " + eventList.size() + " objects");
                            callback.onTaskCompleted();
                        } else {
                            callback.onTaskFailed(e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                callback.onTaskFailed(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Log: "Pinned 1 objects"

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> eventsAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(getActivity(), new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
    public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Event");
        query.orderByAscending("name");
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        return query;
    }
}, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

eventsAdapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onLoading() { }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Retrieved " + parseObjects.size() + " objects");
    }
});
```

Log: "Retrieved 0 objects"

Facebook has confirmed this is a [known bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/881481701867716/).

Is there a workaround?

Comment: the workaround would be to add a user-level ACL, for now, as the local data store does not currently support roles... I'm going to re-open your official bug report and task it internally for development.

Comment: Would it be possible to loop through objects and add current user ACL in addition to the role ACL? Would that behave properly when saving?

Comment: It should.. give it a try and let me know if you have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS documentation now mentions this:

> To access this data protected by Role based ACLs, you will need to
>   ignore ACLs when executing a Local Datastore query:

```
PFQuery *query = [[[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Note"]
                   fromLocalDatastore]
                  ignoreACLs];
```

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#local-datastore-security

It seems the same applies to Android, which has the `ignoreACLs` in the API:

> `public ParseQuery<T> ignoreACLs()`
>
> Ignore ACLs when querying from the Local Datastore.
>
> This is particularly useful when querying for objects with Role based
>   ACLs set on them.

https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#ignoreACLs%28%29

Comment: Looks like LDS is going away anyway. So bummed. https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/237#issuecomment-251261419

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same issue so what i did is the following:

Before you pin the object to the local data store do the following:

```
ParseACL acl = user.getACL();
// Read access only for the logged in user (not public!)
acl.setReadAccess(ParseUser.getCurrentUser(),true); 
user.setACL(acl);
user.pinInBackground();
```

Hope it helps.